# Remove <script> tags using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, script-tag

I want to remove this Google Analytics block, using jQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    try {
        //var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("xxx");
        pageTracker._trackPageview();
    } catch(err) {}
</script>
```

***THE REASON***

Because I am creating a bespoke screen reader convertor for jQuery based on a client specification. It's the Google Analytics that is bugging me.

***THE PROBLEM***

It works with `.remove()` until you navigate away, then press back. Google Analytics hangs.

Comment: You can remove the elements, but I don't think this will do what you want...the script will have already run at that point.

Comment: Are you trying to validate form data? If so, this won't stop an attacker. Server-side validation is necessary.

Comment: No, I am creating some bespoke Javascript based screen-reader functionality.

Comment: Does anyone have any idea? It's driving me insane!!

Comment: What is preventing you from removing the GA code directly from the source code?  Is there a server side scripting language?

Comment: No, there is no serverside code at all. I now have it so it removes the <script> for the Google Analytics, but when I navigate away and press "back", the script dies and Google Analytics just timesout.

Comment: Is it fair game to deploy an http proxy with the product that sanitizes the HTML before sending it through your screen reader?

Comment: @sarnold - Sorry, I didn't understand that...??

Comment: Neurofluxation, I'm curious if your client's needs would be met if you shipped an http proxy with the product. The browser could be configured to use the proxy, and your proxy strips out problematic HTML before it reaches the browser's DOM.

Comment: There is no particular "product" to speak of - it is functionality that they can plugin via a '<script></script>' line. I can see your concern, I have already run them through why this is a bad idea - Still need a solution unfortunetely :'(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
var replacementDoneIn = $(document.body).text(); //remove Google Analytics document.write line
        var regExMatch = /document\.write\(unescape/g;
        var replaceWith = "//document.write";
        var resultSet = replacementDoneIn.replace(regExMatch, replaceWith);
        $("body").html(resultSet);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Perfect, but this does remove EVERY instance of `document.write(unescape` but that's fine for what I need for the moment.

Comment: Note that this will also remove all events from the page.

Comment: haha, how did Davids comment get 3 upvotes when I said mine a good 8 hours before? - random stackoverflow users : )

Answer (score 2):

You can also hook document.write and check if its google anlytics code before stopping it like this:

```
<script>
// Must run before google analytics though
old_document_write = document.write;
document.write = function(str)
{
     if(/* determine if the str is google analyic code */)
         return false; // dont write it
     else
        old_document_write(str);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

So this work as you hope. At least I think it will:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("script").each(function () {
            if (this.innerHTML.length > 0) {
                var googleScriptRegExp = new RegExp("var gaJsHost|var pageTracker");
                if (this.innerHTML.match(googleScriptRegExp) && this.innerHTML.indexOf("innerHTML") == -1)
                    $(this).remove();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Just to explain. I loop through all script tags on the page. If their innerHTML property has a length greater than 0 I then check the innerHTML of the script and if I find the string var gaJsHost or var pageTracker in it. I then make sure that I also don't see innerHTML in it as our script will obviously have these in it. Unless of course you have this code in a script loaded on the page using src in which case this script would not have an innerHTML property set and you can change the if line to just be

```
if (this.innerHTML.match(googleScriptRegExp))
```

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

To actually remove the elements, `jQuery('script:not([src^=http])').remove()` will work.

Comment: You mean from the "view source"? If so, there is no solution in JS. However, it does remove any script blocks without a `src` from the dom. If you want all removed, just use `jQuery('script').remove()`.

Comment: Can't you use their position (using eq())? This will only work of course if the scripts in the same order on every page.

Comment: The problem isn't selecting the right script. By the time this can run the Google Analytics will already have been parsed and run. Ryano's solution above works because it loads the page, parses out the script, then essentially reloads the page with the parsed version.